# Help! Maybe hacked..?

Tags: mac

So after five years I finally got a new Mac.. 
As I was surfing the web my safari page froze up with a pop up saying to contact custermer support my computer has been compromised.. With out thinking I called the number and let the person take control of my computer, after realizing that this is a scam I closed out, hung up and deleted the support help program. 
My question is, is there a way to tell if the lady had a chance to Instal any kind of bug on my computer ? Like the kind that looks threw my camera or copies my key strokes? 
I looked threw my terminal for lsof files but I'm not sure what I'm looking for or If there was anything suspicious..
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you know the name of the Support Software? Otherwise when it is done right and the attacker also knows you password it would be better to do a clean install if you want a good sleep at night.

Comment: Just backup your files and reinstall your system, to be sure

Comment: I don't remember it and I deleted the downloaded files stuff. I'll reinstall my system. Thank you

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349253/my-mac-book-has-been-remotely-hacked

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the Mac, cover up the camera, and avoid using it. I'd also change all my passwords, especially iCloud ASAP. Change them **immediately**! Next I'd give Apple a call tomorrow or, better yet, take it in to an Apple store. You could try a regular computer repair place, but they typically specialize in Windows, not Mac.