# My Mac book has been remotely hacked

Tags: macbook-pro

The problem being I got a phone call and they accessed my laptop and now I have turned the wi fi off because they obviously have access to it. I need in simple terms how I can erase or get rid of this problem

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). At present, your question isn't really that clear. That is, you're telling us your MacBook has been hacked, but we have no context as to *why* you believe this to be the case, so when you say you need to *get rid of this problem* it's not obvious to us what issues you're seeing/experiencing? It'd be great if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/349253/edit) to clarify.

Comment: There’s a huge leap between accepting a phone call and then being hacked over WiFi.  What makes you believe you were hacked?  What behaviors is your Mac exhibiting?

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, they remotely accessed my computer I feel quite silly really making out they were doing security stuff on it, they write out a contract and other stuff all the whilst I was on the phone waiting

Comment: @Allan - A common scam is to socially engineer a naive user into installing remote access software, then taking over the computer. It happened to my mother. Nellie needs help.

Comment: @IconDaemon  - we don’t know what the OP saw or did and a great majority of people believing they were hacked is due to people tending to believe the worst; mostly reinforced by exaggerated media accounts.

Comment: I had a phone call like that, saying I had many issues... Played along for 5 minutes then eventually asked him what system I was running - he replied Windows... I told him he was "worse than useless" as I only have mac os in the house (5 of them...) and put the phone down.. He did not ring back..

Comment: @Allan - You may be right in many cases, but the scammer who attacked my Mom's computer had her install Chrome Remote Access and knew she was using a Mac as soon as he gained access. I just happened to call her cell phone while this was occurring, (because her land-line was busy,) and when she described what was going on, I had her hang up on the scammer and unplug the computer from the router. The scammer hadn't gotten very far, but he had the Users & Groups System Preference open and was in the process of creating an admin account!

Comment: @IconDaemon - I don’t disagree with that at all.   All I’m saying is that it’s too premature to prescribe a solution given that all we have are assumptions

Comment: Better safe than sorry, @Allan. I deal with many naive users in my job, and it is my responsibility to make sure they don't get scammed. One bad scam, and our enterprise network is compromised.

Comment: Your users accept calls from outside “tech support”?  We have trainings on how to identify this.  We also push authority and accountability to the line managers to enforce and discipline where needed.  Finally we conduct random tests to see if people follow the rules.  We don’t have unlimited resources to reimage computers because a user self diagnosed they were hacked.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly if it was me, I would make sure that WiFI **WAS OFF** (Like you said it was.) and then wipe the system completely of any and all data.

*Of course this is assuming that you have a backup of your files previous to the hacking. If not, well then it gets complicated figuring out what files are safe to use.*

So to wipe the Mac, boot it up while holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> until you see the white Apple logo on a black screen.

When you get to the macOS Utilities screen, select disk Utility from the Utilities menu. Select your hard drive on the left and click on Format.

*This will erase EVERYTHING on your drive*

Once that is done quit out of Disk Utility, connect to your WiFi, and proceed with macOS install from the main menu.

This will likely install the version of macOS that your Mac shipped with. You can upgrade it for free once you have done this installation and restored your files from backup.

Answer (score 2):

Nessie: Change your user password immediately. While logged into your account go to `System Preferences, Users & Groups` and click the Change Password... button.

Examine the list of other users, too, and delete any user account which you do not recognize. You will need to click the lock at the bottom-left of the window to delete other accounts, and your account must be an admin account.

[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) is one utility to start with to scan your Mac for any software the scammer has installed. *You'll need to download the software onto a USB key on another Mac.*

Please [read this site](https://www.nextadvisor.com/blog/how-to-avoid-and-recover-from-remote-access-scams/) thoroughly.

Steve Chambers advice to wipe the HD clean is the best method to clean this all up, but can be a daunting process.

Report back with your progress. We're here to help.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem being I got a phone call and they accessed my laptop

How, exactly, did they do that? It is exceptionally unlikely that an unknown random person got into your laptop all by themselves. "Pay us or we delete your data" is called "scareware".

Did you install a program and let them access your laptop? That's your fault.

What you do now is restart your laptop in recovery mode (press command-R at power-on) and restore it from the Time Machine backup the day before this happened. You will lose everything you have done between then and now.

If you don't have a Time Machine backup, follow the instructions from Steve to get a clean system again.

And next time a random person calls about a problem with your computer, just hang up.